# Creating an Uber Jar for Antlr4-based Custom Language

Tags: antlr4, xtext, uberjar

I have created my own simple DSLs using Xtext. Therefore, I know that an Uber Jar created by such a DSL, contains DSL Runtime, IDE, and Xtext dependencies.

My question is, what are the necessary steps that should be followed to create such an Uber Jar for a DSL created using ANTLR4? What are the necessary elements that should be included in the project that I'm intending to build the Uber jar from?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i am not sure what this question targets: if you want to create a uber jar for an app it needs to contain all your app needs. so for a simple java main that calls antlr that would be the main, the generated antlr code and the antlr4-runtime and it (transitive) deps. => i have no idea what your actual problem is

Comment: Is Antlr only used as a language compiler generator / translator? Is it not possible to implement language support (code assistance -> syntax highlighting, code completion etc.) to an Antlr-based DSL using the lexer, parser etc. generated by it?

Comment: do you mean the language server protocol. you can use the LSP4J api to implement that but it is YOUR job to do that. antlr will only give you a parser

Comment: Thank You! So there is NO CONNECTION AT ALL between the antlr4 DSL that I create and LSP4J API?

Comment: there is the protocol. and there is lsp4j which allows you to implement a server (and client) for lsp in java. and there is Xtext. which provides you with a Xtext specific implementation of a LSP4j based server. and there is antlr 4 which just gives you a parser => what xtext does with lsp4j (implement the server) you have to do yourself for antlr or find someone who has already done this in a generic way.

Comment: Thank You! This is what I wanted to know. :-)